# How to drop all subnets outside of the US using iptables

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

I want to block all subnets outside the US. I've made a script that has all of the US subnets in it. I want to disallow or DROP all but my list. Can someone give me an example of how I can start by denying everything?

---

This is the output from -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ftp state NEW
DROP       icmp --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

And these are the rules

```
iptables --F
iptables --policy INPUT DROP
iptables --policy FORWARD DROP
iptables --policy OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 21 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -j DROP
```

**Just for clarity, with these rules, I can still connect to port 21 without my subnet list. I want to block ALL subnets and just open those inside the US.**

Answer (score 3):

If the packet matches an 'ACCEPT' it is immediately accepted.  If it matches a DROP it is immediately dropped.

It sounds like you want only hosts in the US to be able to make a connection to ftp.  There are several ways you can accomplish this.

---

Make lots of complex rules like this.

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT --src 1.2.3.4/24 -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 21 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT --src 4.5.6.7/12 -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 21 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT --src 8.9.1.2/31 -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 21 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

---

Create a new chain, send all the traffic to the chain, use a RETURN for all US subnets and have your final rule in the chain DROP everything else.  This should the better method since less checking of conditions will be done.

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -N USNETS
iptables -A USNETS -s 1.2.3.4/24 -j RETURN
iptables -A USNETS -s 4.5.6.7/12 -j RETURN
iptables -A USNETS -s 8.9.1.2/31 -j RETURN
iptables -A USNETS -j DROP # drop everything that isnt in USNETS
iptables -A INPUT -j USNETS # send everything to USNETS
# PERMIT traffic that
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 21 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

By using a separate change you can even add/remove things from the USNETS chain without resetting the entire firewall as new address space is allocated.  I do seriously question if this idea is worth the effort.  People outside will be able to get in, they will just use a proxy.

---

You could even do it the other way around and do all the port/service in the chain.

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -N SRVCS
iptables -A SRVCS -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 21 -m state --state NEW -j RETURN
iptables -A SRVCS -j DROP # drop everything that isnt in allowed SRVCS
iptables -A INPUT -j SRVCS # send everything to SRVCS
# PERMIT traffic that has been returned from SRVCS
iptables -A INPUT --src 1.2.3.4/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT --src 4.5.6.7/12 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT --src 8.9.1.2/31 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 1):

Set your default policy to DROP, then add ACCEPT rules for all the US-based subnets.

Something like:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -A INPUT --src 1.2.3.4/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT --src 4.5.6.7/12 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT --src 8.9.1.2/31 -j ACCEPT
...
```

Comment: Thanks davr. I already have iptables -P INPUT DROP defined as my first rule however, without my implemented list, I can still connect. Wouldn't this indicate that anyone can connect from any subnet?

Comment: Actually, my first rule is to flush the rules and then iptables -P INPUT DROP is listed second.

Comment: Something's wrong with your rules.  If you want help, post your `iptables -L -n` and `iptables -t nat -L -n` as well as the script that's specifying them.  davr's recommendation is correct.

Comment: People are voting up this answer but nobody is looking at my rules and telling me where I'm going wrong. If this is the right answer, tell me how to implement it so that it actually works.

Comment: -1.  If you read between the lines a bit it is clear the OP wants to permit US traffic to only certain ports/services.  This set of rules would permit US Subnets to do anything which is almost certainly not what is desired.

Comment: Jim, the first rule of your input table causes the issue. It allows every tcp connection through your firewall. If you replace this with the ACCEPT lists as proposed above, it should work.

Comment: @Zoredache: There was no mention of specific ports or services at all when I first answered.

Answer (score 1):

If you, however, decide to make huge sets for blocking you should look into [ipset](http://ipset.netfilter.org/) which can handle very big lists at very fast speeds.

With ipset you can have a single iptable rule acting on one set. No need for rules for every subnet.

However, there is no support in the mainstream kernel for ipset. You need to compile the module yourself. Instructions can be found at the ipset site.

Answer (score 0):

I am the OP (Jim) and I came back to this thread to see if there were any new answers. I also came back to personally thank Zoredache for all of his help and the effort that he put into his answer. I have been around a UNIX environment for many, many years and have little to no experience with "Linux" packet filters but I knew that **davr and Warner** were incorrect and just concluded after all the time that I waited for them to come back and redeem themselves, that they didn't know what the right answer was.

So, thank you Zoredache again for all of your help! I tend to agree with you about blocking all countries in that it is not worth it; they can just proxy in if they want too.